# How to create a custom PyTorch dataset when the order and the total number of training samples is not known in advance?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a 42 GB jsonl file. Every element of this file is a json object. I create training samples from every json object. But the number of training samples from every json object that I extract can vary between 0 to 5 samples. What is the best way to create a custom PyTorch dataset without reading the entire jsonl file in memory?

This is the dataset I am talking about - [Google Natural Questions](https://ai.google.com/research/NaturalQuestions/download).

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of options.

1. The simplest option, if having lots of small files is not a problem, is to preprocess each json object into a single file. Then you can just read each one depending on the index requested. E.g

```py
    class SingleFileDataset(Dataset):
        def __init__(self, list_of_file_paths):
            self.list_of_file_paths = list_of_file_paths

        def __getitem__(self, index):
            return np.load(self.list_of_file_paths[index]) # Or equivalent reading code for single file
```

2. You can also split the data into a constant number of files, and then calculate, given the index, which file the sample resides in. Then you need to open that file into memory and read the appropriate index. This gives a trade-off between disk access and memory usage. Assume you have `n` samples, and we split the samples into `c` files evenly during preprocessing. Now, to read the sample at index `i` we would do

```py
    class SplitIntoFilesDataset(Dataset):
        def __init__(self, list_of_file_paths, n_splits):
            self.list_of_file_paths = list_of_file_paths
            self.n_splits = n_splits

        def __getitem__(self, index):
            # index // n_splits is the relevant file, and 
            # index % len(self) is the index in in that file
            file_to_load = self.list_of_file_paths[index // self.n_splits]
            # Load file
            file = np.load(file)
            datapoint = file[index % len(self)]
```

3. Finally, you could use a [HDF5](https://www.h5py.org/) file that allows access to rows on disk. This is possibly the best solution if you have a lot of data, since the data will be close on disk. There's an implementation [here](https://www.tinymind.com/learn/terms/hdf5#pytorch) which I have copy pasted below:

   ```py
   import h5py
   import torch
   import torch.utils.data as data
   class H5Dataset(data.Dataset):

       def __init__(self, file_path):
           super(H5Dataset, self).__init__()
           h5_file = h5py.File(file_path)
           self.data = h5_file.get('data')
           self.target = h5_file.get('label')

       def __getitem__(self, index):            
           return (torch.from_numpy(self.data[index,:,:,:]).float(),
                   torch.from_numpy(self.target[index,:,:,:]).float())

       def __len__(self):
           return self.data.shape[0]
   ```

Comment: I can pre-process each json object into samples. But the problem is some json objects do not return any sample and some return up to 5 samples. How to write the __getitem__ method in this case?

Comment: Are the samples in the 5 sample case supposed to be distinct or somehow grouped? If they are distinct, just split them during preprocessing. If they should be used as one sample, then there's no problem just return whatever is in the object?

Comment: This would work. I can just get the json objects in a batch and split them before calling the model. Though I was looking for a more direct way to do this. Thanks.