# Using a generator with pickled data in a Dataloader for PyTorch

Tags: python, dataset, generator, pickle, pytorch

I have done some preprocessing and feature selection before, and I have a pickle training input data that consists of list of lists, e.g. (but pickled)

```
[[1,5,45,13], [23,256,4,2], [1,12,88,78], [-1]]
[[12,45,77,325], [23,257,5,28], [3,7,48,178], [12,77,89,99]]
[[13,22,78,89], [12,33,97], [-1], [-1]]
```

`[-1]` is a padding token, but I don't think that matters.

Because the file is numerous of gigabytes, I wish to spare memory and use a generator to read in the pickle line by line (list by list). I already found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20725705/1150683) that could be helpful. This would like follows:

```
def yield_from_pickle(pfin):
    with open(pfin, 'rb') as fhin:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(fhin)
            except EOFError:
                break
```

The next thing is, that I wish to use this data in a PyTorch (1.0.1) [Dataloader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader). From what I found in other answers, I must feed it a [Dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) which you can subset, but which must contain `__len__` and `__getitem__`. It could like this:

```
class TextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, pfin):
        self.pfin = pfin

    def __len__(self):
        # memory-lenient way but exhaust generator?
        return sum(1 for _ in self.yield_from_pickle())

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # ???
        pass

    def yield_from_pickle(self):
        with open(self.pfin, 'rb') as fhin:
            while True:
                try:
                    yield pickle.load(fhin)
                except EOFError:
                    break
```

But I am not at all sure if this is even possible. How can I implement `__len__` and `__getitem__` in a sensible way? I don't think what I am doing with `__len__` is a good idea because that'll exhaust the generator, and I have no idea at all how to safely implement `__getitem__` while retaining the generator.

Is there a better way? To summarize, I want to build a Dataset that can be fed to PyTorch's Dataloader (because of its multiprocessing abilities) but in a memory-efficient way where I don't have to read the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571377/how-to-create-a-custom-pytorch-dataset-when-the-order-and-the-total-number-of-tr/54572327#54572327) for your options.

In short, you need to either preprocess each sample into separate files, or use a data format that does not need to be loaded fully into memory for reading.